# How to send mail inside app using Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a feedback page that allow users to submit issues. I tried using Mailer to send emails, not sure if that is the best solution. Wanted to get people's ideas?

Comment: Checkout this tutorial it will be helpful

Comment: https://achinthaisuru444.medium.com/sending-emails-using-flutter-f588387280db

Answer (score 2):

You can use url_launcher:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

It provides a great example:

```
final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
  scheme: 'mailto',
  path: 'smith@example.com',
  queryParameters: {
    'subject': 'Example Subject & Symbols are allowed!'
  }
);

// ...

// mailto:smith@example.com?subject=Example+Subject+%26+Symbols+are+allowed%21
launch(_emailLaunchUri.toString());
```

This would launch e-mail app with your data entered for your user.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Package Flutter Email Sender](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_email_sender) (you can even send html format)

```
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';
```

Your button:

```dart
onTap: () async {await sendEmail(user.email);} // replace user.email with email String
```

The function:

```dart
sendEmail(String emailAddress) async {
  final Email email = Email(
    body:
    'Hello World',
    subject: 'Testing email on flutter',
    recipients: [emailAddress],
    //cc: ['cc@example.com'],
    //bcc: ['bcc@example.com'],
    //attachmentPaths: ['/path/to/attachment.zip'],
    isHTML: false,
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use mailer, the user does not have to write their own email and the your app won't redirect them to the mail app to write a specific email